# openerp-server 5.0 start error - bzr error

Tags: python, error-handling, odoo, bazaar

Actually when I launch the openerp-server 5.0 I'm getting following error and I have no clue why it is happening. Maybe after a system update?

bzr: error: not a branch: "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/".

I have looked everywhere on Google but no answer. Do you have any idea?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error shows `python2.5` - do you really use so old version ?

Comment: Hello furas, thanks for your comments and suggestions. After a reboot the error went off.